# In Django, how to rename user model?

Tags: django

I trying to rename my user model CustomUser => User

Here what I've done:

1. Rename Python class and all references
2. makemigrations

```
Did you rename the accounts.CustomUser model to User? [y/N] y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 168, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 186, in _detect_changes
    self.generate_altered_fields()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 959, in generate_altered_fields
    dependencies.extend(self._get_dependencies_for_foreign_key(new_field))
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 1086, in _get_dependencies_for_foreign_key
    dep_app_label = field.remote_field.model._meta.app_label
AttributeError: 'SettingsReference' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

So I'm stuck with this exception, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem, here is how I handled it:

Assuming that your user models are in an app called "users":

Leave the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting at the old value (`users.CustomUser`).

In users/model.py, rename the class from `CustomUser` to User add a new class with the old name that inherits from the new name

```
class CustomUser(User):
    pass
```

Use `manage.py` to create an empty migration file

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty users
```

Open the newly create migration file, and add this operation:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RenameModel('CustomUser', 'User')
]
```

Migrate the changes

```
python manage.py migrate users
```

Then you can go and change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `users.User` and remove the `CustomUser` class from `users/model.py`

I reference the user model using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` when defining a `ForeignKey` and `get_user_model()` from `django.contrib.auth` anywhere else so I had no other references that needed to be changed.